# Does Artifactory support HA mode with the embedded Derby database?

Tags: artifactory, high-availability

It is not clear from the JFrog documentation, if the HA deployment of Artifactory can be made using the embedded Derby database or it must always be external DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Artifactory requires and external database when installed in HA mode. This requirement is specified in the HA installation and setup document as part of the [requirements](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/HA+Installation+and+Setup#HAInstallationandSetup-Requirements) section.
The reason for such a requirement is that all cluster nodes are sharing the same database and this cannot be done with the embedded derby.